# Do orthogonal functions map to orthogonal functions under a conformal transformation?

Tags: conformal-geometry, spherical-harmonics

Let's say we have a set of orthogonal functions (such as spherical harmonics) over some manifold such that (for a simple one dimensional example):

$$\delta_{nm}=\int_{M}Y_{n}(x)Y_{m}(x)dx$$

Now lets consider transforming the setup to a conformally related space. Do we still have that:

$$\delta_{nm}=\int_{M'}Y'_{n}(x')Y'_{m}(x')dx'$$

Given that Conformal transformations preserve angles I expect the answer is a definitive YES. Does anyone know for sure? I'm interested in spherical harmonics on the $S^{3}$ mapped to the Bohr one point compactification of $R^{3}$.

Comment: Is $Y'_n(T(x))$ the same _number_ as $Y_n(x)$, or does your transformation of the $Y$s include scaling by the stretch/shrink factor of $T$ at each point?

Comment: @HenningMakholm  In the general case, I would say no, the values would differ after transformation, so that perhaps the normalization constant for the harmonics would be different. Consider for example the mapping of harmonics on $S^2$ to a sphere $S^2$ with a different radius than the first. (for a very simple example)

Comment: I cannot "consider for example" a mapping that you have not defined what does.

Comment: @HenningMakholm   I simply meant a straightforward dilation of the sphere such that harmonics are mapped to harmonics say the nth mode harmonic would be mapped to the same mode on the larger sphere. Apologies, physics student here though I want to learn more math

Answer (score 2):

> Conformal transformations preserve angles

There is some confusion here. The angles that they preserve are angles between vectors drawn on the space $M$ (technically, tangent vectors to $M$). This is totally different from angles between functions defined on $M$, where we use inner product $\langle f, g\rangle =\int_M fg$. It may help to realize that the angle between functions depends only on the **measure** with which we equip the space $M$, not on its **metric**.

In any case, the following is true for any diffeomorphism $\varphi:M'\to M$ between Riemannian manifolds (equipped with the Riemannian volume).

- If the functions $Y_n$ are orthogonal on $M$, then the functions $Y'_n(y) = Y_n(\varphi(y)) \sqrt{|J_\varphi(y)|}$ are orthogonal on $M'$, where $J_\varphi$ is the Jacobian determinant of $\varphi$. This follows from the change of variable formula,
  $$
  \int_{M'}Y_n'(y)Y_m'(y)\,dy = \int_{M'}Y_n(\varphi(y))Y_m(\varphi(y)) |J_\varphi(y)|\,dy = \int_M Y_n(x)Y_m(x)\,dx = \delta_{mn}
  $$
- If you simply define $Y_n'(y) = Y_n(\varphi(y))$, then the above does not work and $Y_n'$ are not orthogonal in general.

Conformality plays no role here.

Comment: @Crazy_Ivan    +1 and thank you. I'm a physics student so I have to learn a lot of this on my own. Usually we define in physics an invariant volume element via the square root of the metric determinant, in this context isn't this also the measure we're equipping the space with? How are the two related. Thank you again!!